# Use of discriminent in proving that the points of unramification is open....

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am confused about Shaferevich Varieties in Projective Space proposition 2.29:

If $f : X \to Y$ is a finite map between irreducible varieties, with $Y$ normal, then the set of points in $Y$ over which $f$ is unramified is open.

Essentially, his argument piggybacks on the previous proposition, which proves that the number of points in each preimage is bounded by the degree of $f$. The way that argument goes is he finds some function $a$ that distinguishes the preimages of a fixed point, and observes that this function is integral over the pullback coordinate ring of $Y$, hence at each solution to the problem $f(x) = y$, we are given a unique solution to a fixed polynomial of degree less than $n$. This fixed polynomial from evaluating the (integral) minimal polynomial $F$ of $a$ at the solution points $f(x) = y$, and observing that the coefficients of this polynomial are fixed at those solutions...

Now, to prove the next proposition, has wants to argue that the discriminent of $F$ vanishes at $y'$ only if $f$ is ramified at $y'$. I'm confused, because $F$ was specifically constructed for $a$, which was specifically constructed to distinguish the preimages of the point $y$. Moreover, even if $F(y')$ has distinct roots, why should $a$ assume all of these roots on the preimage set?

Hopefully that is clear. It may be easier to just read his argument.

Thanks!